# Delete file in target directory only if not present in source directory

Tags: c#, file, copy, backup

I am trying to make a program to backup my files. I have the copy portion working already but I would like to delete any directory or file not present in the source directory from the destination directory.

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
// Get existing files in destination
string[] existingTargetFiles = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// Get existing directories in destination
    string[] existingTargetDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

// Compare and delete directories that exist in destination but not source
foreach (string existingDirectory in existingTargetDirectories)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(sourceDir, existingDirectory)))
        Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(targetDir, existingDirectory));
    }
}

// Compare and delete files that exist in destination but not source
foreach (string existingFiles in existingTargetFiles)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(sourceDir, existingFiles)))
        Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(targetDir, existingFiles));
}
```

}

Any thoughts on how to make something like this work?

Comment: you have to solve this recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes to get relative file path then combine it with source dir, using file class for file deletion etc..

I have changed the order to file deletion first ,otherwise it will cause consistency issue of file not found because folder was deleted before that in some scenario (as you are getting files list recursively using  `Directory.GetFiles(targetDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` )

```
        // Get existing files in destination
        string[] existingTargetFiles = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        // Get existing directories in destination
        string[] existingTargetDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        // Compare and delete files that exist in destination but not source
        foreach (string existingFiles in existingTargetFiles)
        {

            if (!File.Exists(existingFiles.Replace(targetDir, sourceDir)))
            {

                File.Delete(existingFiles);
            }
        }
        // Compare and delete directories that exist in destination but not source
        foreach (string existingDirectory in existingTargetDirectories)
        {

            if (!Directory.Exists(existingDirectory.Replace(targetDir, sourceDir)))
            {
                Directory.Delete(existingDirectory,true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This worked well for me. I also noticed that I had Directory.Delete() for both of my foreach loops and no File.Delete() at all! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following Recursive copy function I found online which copies all files, sub-directories deep down. I have created a recursive delete function to delete all files in the target directory which does not exist in the source directory. This will go through all sub-directories as well

`Utilities.cs`:

```
public static void Copy(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
{
    DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
    DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

    CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
}

private static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);

    // Copy each file into the new directory.
    foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
    {
        var destinationFile = Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name);
        fi.CopyTo(destinationFile, true);
    }

    // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
    {
        DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
        CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
    }
}

public static void Delete(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
{
    DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
    DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

    DeleteAll(diSource, diTarget);
}

private static void DeleteAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    if (!source.Exists)
    {
        target.Delete(true);
        return;
    }

    // Delete each existing file in target directory not existing in the source directory.
    foreach (FileInfo fi in target.GetFiles())
    {
        var sourceFile = Path.Combine(source.FullName, fi.Name);
        if (!File.Exists(sourceFile)) //Source file doesn't exist, delete target file
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }
    }

    // Delete non existing files in each subdirectory using recursion.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diTargetSubDir in target.GetDirectories())
    {
        DirectoryInfo nextSourceSubDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(source.FullName, diTargetSubDir.Name));
        DeleteAll(nextSourceSubDir, diTargetSubDir);
    }
}
```

You can use the above simply as:

```
string SourcePath = @"C:\MySourceFolder\";
string PublishPath = @"C:\Published\";

Utilities.Copy(SourcePath, PublishPath);
Utilities.Delete(SourcePath, PublishPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will delete all those files from destination directory  which exists in destination directory but not in source directory :

```
       //Source path directory
        string sourceDir = @"G:\Sample\Source";
        //Target path directory
        string targetDir = @"G:\Sample\Destination";

        //Function that will return name of directory or file
        public static string GetDirectoryName(string path)
        {
            return path.Substring((path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1));
        }

        // Get existing files in destination
        string[] existingTargetFiles = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        // Get existing files in source
        string[] existingSourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        // Get existing directories in destination
        string[] existingTargetDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        // Get existing directories in source
        string[] existingSourceDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


        // Compare and delete files that exist in destination but not source
        string TargetFileName = "";
        string SourceFileName = "";
        bool IsTargetFileIsInSourceFileList = false;
        //Getting each single file from Target directory.
        foreach (string existingFiles in existingTargetFiles)
        {
            //Getting only name of current file.
            TargetFileName = GetDirectoryName(existingFiles);
            //Let current file is not present in list of source files. 
            IsTargetFileIsInSourceFileList = false;
            //Getting each single file from Source directory.
            //If current file of Target directory not exists in list of source directory files
            //then IsTargetFileIsInSourceFileList would be false 
            //And if exists the IsTargetFileIsInSourceFileList would be true.
            foreach (string existingSourceFile in existingSourceFiles)
            {
                SourceFileName = GetDirectoryName(existingSourceFile);
                if (string.Equals(TargetFileName, SourceFileName))
                {
                    IsTargetFileIsInSourceFileList = true;
                    break;

                }
            }
            //if IsTargetFileIsInSourceFileList is false and delete the file
            if (!IsTargetFileIsInSourceFileList)
            {
                File.Delete(existingFiles);
            }

        }


        // Compare and delete directories that exist in destination but not source
        foreach (string existingDirectory in existingTargetDirectories)
        {
            //Getting name of directory from path of current directory taken from list.
            string sourceDirPath = Path.Combine(sourceDir, GetDirectoryName(existingDirectory));
            //if name of current directory is not present in list of directories of source
            //Delete the directory
            if (!existingSourceDirectories.Contains(sourceDirPath))
            {
                Directory.Delete(existingDirectory);
            }

        }
```